# FCM messaging with Realtime Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

My app using FireBaserealtime database and storage.Now i am struck in the part of push notification FCM.Please help anyone how to do.Is there anyway,without open firebase console and send notification to devices?Or please help me to send notification by coding.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use Advance Rest client to send a notification to the device.
Use the link to add extension to chrome
```

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
    [image]
    Notification will not receive when app kill, thus you need to Register Receiver to get Notification

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class OnBootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
    Intent i = new Intent("com.android.pushnotify.MyFirebaseMessagingService");
        i.setClass(context, MyFirebaseMessagingService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}

add inside Manifest.xml(Application tag)

 <receiver android:name="com.androidbash.androidbashfirebasepushnotify.OnBootBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: Ofcourse...Kindlly share quries in firebase Db,I got some idea..but cant understand fully.Please help me in that part.

Comment: you can send the notification to the device with firebase console or Advance rest client and have already added it inside answer.

Comment: I am asking about firebase DB queries .I m new to FireBase

Comment: but this is notification part, and there is no need of implementing DB Query.