# Firebase Cloud Messaging - onMessageReceived not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to make a simple notification feature in my app. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mz4VcuR0-qA) YouTube video and both of these Firebase documentation URLs [1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message) and [2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) plus the Firebase tool assistant in Android Studio (which says I'm connected to Firebase). For some reason, following these steps and documents on my older app (which code is posted below), it won't allow me to receive notifications. However, if I follow the same steps on a brand new app it works perfectly. I tested both apps on the same physical device and environment in the background, active and terminated states. Every time the new demo app I created works with no issue but my older app which I want notifications in does not work. Both tested without getting the device ID. I do not even get any error logs or any TAG log. I think one of my compiled projects is interfering, not sure exactly what but I might have to look there.

I also checked out all these SO posts already: [1](http://android%20-%20FireBase%20Cloud%20Messaging%20Not%20Working%20-%20Stack%20Overflow)[2](http://android%20-%20Firebase%20cloud%20messaging%20notification%20not%20received%20by%20...)[3](http://Firebase%20notification%20not%20working%20on%20Android%20VIRTUAL%20devices%20...) and more

PS. I removed my package name below, I checked multiple times on FireBase and they match so I know that is not the issue. However, my new demo app's FireBase shows that my app connected but my older app's FireBase did not. Also, I've set a bounty before and still running into the same issue.

Here's my problematic code:

Notification.java (its a service like the documentation asks)

```
public class Notification extends FirebaseMessagingService {
public Notification() {
}
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));

    Log.d("FMC", "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void showNotification(String message) {
    Intent i=new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("FCM TITLE").setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pt_icon)
            .setDefaults(android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build());
}
}
```

> Notice I do not even get a log in the notification.java above.

**Project.gradle**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()

    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    google()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 16
    versionName "2.6"
}
dexOptions {
    jumboMode = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
//Code below is added to fix random error ("Fix the issues identified by lint")
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
//Removed the 0.2.+
compile 'com.daprlabs.aaron:cardstack:0.3.1-beta0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+"
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'

compile 'com.github.danylovolokh:video-player-manager:0.2.0'
compile 'com.github.danylovolokh:list-visibility-utils:0.2.0'



implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'


compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'


compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile files('libs/sinch-android-rtc-3.9.14.jar')
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.4.4'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.2.6'
compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.5.0'
compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
compile 'com.victor:lib:1.0.4'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.0'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.5'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:2.3.8'
compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.3.9'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
compile 'com.mxn.soul:flowingdrawer-core:1.2.2'
compile 'com.github.rengwuxian:MaterialEditText:2.1.4'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:3.2.5'
compile 'in.srain.cube:ultra-ptr:1.0.11'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v4:23.+'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!--
so the app can be found on tablets Google Play

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/> -->
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> -->
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> -->

<grant-uri-permission
    android:path="string"
    android:pathPattern="string"
    android:pathPrefix="string" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/_icon"
    android:label=""
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    tools:node="replace">
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".Notification">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!-- &lt;!&ndash; -->
    <!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages. -->
    <!-- See README() for more. -->
    <!-- &ndash;&gt; -->
    <!-- <meta-data -->
    <!-- android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" -->
    <!-- android:resource="@drawable/pt_icon" /> -->
    <!-- &lt;!&ndash; -->
    <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming -->
    <!-- notification message. See README() for more. -->
    <!-- &ndash;&gt; -->
    <!-- <meta-data -->
    <!-- android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" -->
    <!-- android:resource="@color/colorAccent" /> -->

    <activity android:name=".SignInForm" />
    <activity android:name=".SignUpPage" />
    <activity android:name=".SellerFillOutForm" />
    <activity android:name=".BuyerFillOutForm" />
    <activity
        android:name=".BuyerHomePage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_buyer_home_page" />

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="http" />

    <activity android:name=".VideoPlayerActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".BackgroundTask" />

    <service
        android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <activity android:name=".EnterCreditCard" />
    <activity android:name=".PickMeeting" />
    <activity android:name=".HowBillingWorks" />
    <activity android:name=".ReBillingPlan" />
    <activity android:name=".PayBill" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Buyer_Home_Page"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation" />
    <activity android:name=".Seller_Home_Page" />
    <activity android:name=".ProductList" />
    <activity android:name=".EditProduct" />
    <activity android:name=".EditSellerAccount" />
    <activity android:name=".EditBuyerAccount" />
    <activity android:name=".Video_Calling.incomingVideoCall" />
    <activity android:name=".Video_Calling.CallScreenActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SellerAnalytics" />
    <activity android:name=".Swipe_Layout.SwipeLayout" />
    <activity android:name=".Swipe_Layout.PopUpActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

> **Working code below (the app I made just to test my steps and works 100%):**

**Notifaction.java**

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class Notifaction extends FirebaseMessagingService {
public Notifaction() {
}
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
}

private void showNotification(String message) {
    Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("FCM TITLE").setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build());
}
}
```

**AndroidManiest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".Notifaction">
        <intent-filter>
            <action 
android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>

</manifest>
```

**app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Project.grdle**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also, I added the .json file to both projects. Here is a screenshot:
[image: link].

Comment: Could it be one of the compile libraries I use not let _me_ interact with Firebase?*

Comment: do you receive any default notifications when sending from firebase console?

Comment: and when you run the App you receive log msg that "Firebase initialized successfully"?

Comment: I do not receive any notification whatsoever and not even a "Firebase initialized successfully" log :/

Comment: you do not have any log from firebase?

Comment: I do not get receive anything

Comment: on which android OS version you are testing?

Comment: Is the notification not working in both foreground and background mode?

Comment: Also if you are sending message to specific device, have you cross checked if the firebase token is correct?

Answer (score 5):

If you are receiving device token and you have server api key then check your code working properly or not using  [pushtry](http://pushtry.com/) .
it will give error like **Invalid Registration**, **404 Error** etc if you have done any mistake in your code.
and for implementation of FCM, you can follow this tutorial- [FCM Tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

One more thing i have notice in your `build.gradle`file there is no any `applicationId "Package Name"` in `defaultConfig`.
I am not sure but this is package name and used when we create project on firebase console (Project name with package)

Comment: I removed the package name it has private info but I connected it with the Firebase Assistant Tool in Android Studio and on the Firebase website. Everything says its connected. Also, I did add the .json file.

Comment: this answer was auto-selected for the +25. This answer did not solve my issue.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely your notifications are not showing due to **Android Oreo** new [notifications model](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html) which requires to specify channels definitions in order to build and show notifications. Also in your app.gradle, you are targeting android **version 26** which is **Android Oreo**, so you will have to implement the code below either way.

It is easy to adopt. all you need to do is:

**1. define a notification channel in your YourApplicationClass.onCreate()**

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            NotificationChannel chan1 = new NotificationChannel(
                YOUR_DESIRED_CHANNEL_ID_STRING,
                YOUR_DESIRED_CHANNEL_LABEL_STRING, 
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            chan1.setDescription(YOUR_DESIRED_CHANNEL_DESC_STRING);//OPTIONAL
            chan1.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);//OPTIONAL     
            chan1.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);//OPTIONAL
            chan1.setShowBadge(true);//OPTIONAL

            getManager().createNotificationChannel(chan1);
        }
```

**2. replace you notification builder with this constructor**

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=
new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, YOUR_DESIRED_CHANNEL_ID_STRING);
```

**Good to know that you can define more than one channel with different properties targeting Android Oreo and higher**

Comment: If that's the case shouldn't my new app not work because it also targets Android Oreo and it doesn't follow the new notifications model?

Comment: you might be facing a different kind of problem or bug, but I am 100% sure that without specifying channels, your app will fail to show notifications on devices running android O (26)... are you testing both of your apps on the same device/android version? also do both apps have the same code implementation? (maybe I could help further)

Comment: I do test both apps on the same device and both apps have all there respected code above

Comment: 2 silly questions but helps debugging:
- did you place the same json file in both projects?
- how are you sending your notifications to devices? firebase console?

after a second look.. your code looks fine

Comment: I have their .json file for each project and I'm sending a notification via firebase console. Exactly that's why I am super stuck :/

Comment: In that case, you are left with one of the following:

1 make sure not to use the same push ID for both apps cause its unique by app and not by device.

2 make sure that you are using the correct and up-to-date Push ID since push Ids get changed every now and then. Therefore I suggest that you implement FirebaseInstanceIdService (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService) which I fail to see implemented in your code.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)
You don't seem to have a service that extends `FirebaseInstanceIdService` to manage the token creation/rotation. [Here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java) is a example code. The token you need to send the push notifications to a specific device is received by this class.

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**EDIT**:

Okay, this error is bugging me now. I looked at your dependency tree and I see you're repeating some of them. For example you have three version of:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
```

Maybe you should clear that out to the newest version, or match it with the working version. Also you're using the new gradle plugin, but you haven't updated your depedencies to use `implementation` instead of `compile` in most cases, maybe try that as well? Here's [why](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html?hl=pt-br) you should do it.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
//Removed the 0.2.+
compile 'com.daprlabs.aaron:cardstack:0.3.1-beta0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+"
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'

compile 'com.github.danylovolokh:video-player-manager:0.2.0'
compile 'com.github.danylovolokh:list-visibility-utils:0.2.0'



implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'


compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'


compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile files('libs/sinch-android-rtc-3.9.14.jar')
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.4.4'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.2.6'
compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.5.0'
compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
compile 'com.victor:lib:1.0.4'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.0'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.5'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:2.3.8'
compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.3.9'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
compile 'com.mxn.soul:flowingdrawer-core:1.2.2'
compile 'com.github.rengwuxian:MaterialEditText:2.1.4'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:3.2.5'
compile 'in.srain.cube:ultra-ptr:1.0.11'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v4:23.+'
}
```

Also, update your dependencies and use implementation instead of compile:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
```

Comment: I dont have it in my quick app that i made and it works

Comment: in the video you said you used, around 11:03 the guy teaches how to create the FirebaseInstanceIdService, did you use the video for the quick app?

Comment: No the ID service is used to gain the token to subscribe to topic notifications but i just want to send a notification to everyone, I will play with topics and more after

Comment: Okay, if you're not sending the notification to the device via token, how are you sending it?

Comment: Because the ID service is also used to generate the token to send to the server for communication. For example, if I want my app to have push notifications from firebase I save that token to the real time database and use it to direct messages to my device.

Comment: Thats if you want to send to a single device or use the token to subscribe the phone to a notification topic. I want to send a notification to everyone like in the quick app i made. Do you want to see the working code?

Comment: this is a wild guess, but have you tried make the manifest equal. I mean, just testing removing your other activities and leaving just the launcher activity like in the app that's working? The same with the build.gradle, you two options (besides the dependencies) that you don't have in the other app dexOptions, lintOptions and productFlavors

Answer (score 3):

> // this help to start FCM service in background when phone restart.

```
Add receiver in Manifest.xml

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<receiver android:name=".OnBootBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>

OnBootBroadcastReceiver.class

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class OnBootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent("com.examle.FirebaseMessagingReceiveService");
        i.setClass(context, FirebaseMessagingReceiveService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Have you check the type of notification (message or Data) becuase
in your onMessageReceived you have handle only data message.
try to print log in this message.
2. if you have implement GCM in previous project and GCM dependencies, 
may be some confict with fcm.

Comment: Every time I test I check my logs for "FCM" and it has never shown up. Also, I believe I used GCM awhile ago, can you help me point out how to get rid of it?

Comment: when you send notification to device, try to get the log, this will help.. and check that fcm token generate or not, if token is valid then only you receive notification.

Comment: Again every time I test anything I always check my logs for "FMC" and I do not want to send the notification to my device only, I want to send a notification to everyone.

Comment: first check with your device fcm token, you can use advance rest client chrome extension to send notification

Comment: check from this below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816663/fcm-messaging-with-realtime-firebase-database

Answer (score 3):

Hope you know the types of notifications, For sending notification you have to use custom server or something like postman , for more information, please refer the answer of these question :

[How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase)

Anyways, you have to call handleIntent(Intent intent) method in your FirebaseMessagingService in order to call onMessageReceived()  method..

Here is my complete working code, notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase.

build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    //firebase analytics and ads
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abc.xyz">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <!-- [START fcm_default_icon] -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
        <!-- [END fcm_default_icon] -->
        <!-- [START fcm_default_channel] -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
        <!-- [END fcm_default_channel] -->

        <service
            android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".services.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".services.MyJobService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService.java :

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Log.e(TAG, "handleIntent");
        try
        {
            if (intent.getExtras() != null)
            {
                RemoteMessage.Builder builder = new RemoteMessage.Builder("MyFirebaseMessagingService");

                for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet())
                {
                    builder.addData(key, intent.getExtras().get(key).toString());
                }

                onMessageReceived(builder.build());
            }
            else
            {
                super.handleIntent(intent);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            super.handleIntent(intent);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // Not getting messages here? See why this may be:
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification received Successfully");
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
                scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                handleNow();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Schedule a job using FirebaseJobDispatcher.
     */
    private void scheduleJob() {
        // [START dispatch_job]
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
        Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(MyJobService.class)
                .setTag("my-job-tag")
                .build();
        dispatcher.schedule(myJob);
        // [END dispatch_job]
    }

    /**
     * Handle time allotted to BroadcastReceivers.
     */
    private void handleNow() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                        .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java :

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        Log.e(TAG, "onTokenRefresh");
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.e(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }
}
```

MyJobService.java

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class MyJobService extends JobService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyJobService";

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
        // Do some work here
        Log.e(TAG, "Inside MyJobService");
        return false; // Answers the question: "Is there still work going on?"
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Inside MyJobService");
        return false; // Answers the question: "Should this job be retried?"
    }
}
```

MyApplication.java :

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // active JobSchedulerReceiver
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(getPackageName() + ".receiver.JobSchedulerReceiver");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.e(TAG, "Inside MainActivity");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // Create channel to show notifications.
            String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
            String channelName = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_name);
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            assert notificationManager != null;
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW));
        }

        // If a notification message is tapped, any data accompanying the notification
        // message is available in the intent extras. In this sample the launcher
        // intent is fired when the notification is tapped, so any accompanying data would
        // be handled here. If you want a different intent fired, set the click_action
        // field of the notification message to the desired intent. The launcher intent
        // is used when no click_action is specified.
        //
        // Handle possible data accompanying notification message.
        // [START handle_data_extras]
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
                Log.e(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
            }
        }
        // [END handle_data_extras]

        Button subscribeButton = findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton);
        subscribeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // [START subscribe_topics]
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
                // [END subscribe_topics]

                // Log and toast
                String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
                Log.e(TAG, msg);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        Button logTokenButton = findViewById(R.id.logTokenButton);
        logTokenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Get token
                String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

                // Log and toast
                String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
                Log.e(TAG, msg);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Even I faced the same issue, It got resolved by adding full path **android:name** service in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name="com.testapp.Notifaction">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

give try once & let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not receive any log event from Firebase check the following steps:

- Go you your Firebase project console enter project settings and check the if the package name is correct.
- Download the JSON file again and copy it into `app/` module (change project perspective from Android to project), **MAKE SURE file name is** `google-services.json`
- Run your project, go to logcat search for keyword `Firebase`, in case of success you will see message:

> I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful

Answer (score 2):

Let's go step by step. I'll check all your code compared to my actual project, which is working on production with the last version of Firebase Messaging service:

- Your dependencies on gradle looks fine, but you just need   `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2"`
- Could you try to rename your class to something different? `Notification` name maybe its interaction with the own Android Notification class. Also remember that it should have an Empty constructor(but I see in your code that you have it)

Call it MessagingController for example and put it on your manifest inside `<application>` like:

```
   <!--Service to control messaging requests-->
        <service
            android:name=".messaging.controller.MessagingController"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
```

Also, don't forget that you need an instance of `FirebaseInstanceService`, this is required like the [Official Doc says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client):

> A service that extends FirebaseInstanceIdService to handle the creation, rotation, and updating of registration tokens. This is required for sending to specific devices or for creating device groups.

```
<!--Firebase instance service to renew messaging tokens-->
        <service
            android:name=".messaging.service.FirebaseInstanceService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

- Are you sending the notifications from the Firebase Console? Or using Firebase Cloud functions? In Both cases, are you introducing the right token? If you put a timed out token Firebase console will show you an error, you should add the notification like this:

[image]

- OK, at this point, with your code this should be at least receiving the notifications in your logs,
- If you want you can check the next project which is a application Skeleton to build a notification system. Maybe it will help you too: https://github.com/FrangSierra/PushNotificationSkeleton
- Finally if you want to check some cloud function code about how to send notifications from the server, I suggest you to give a look to the [this repository](https://github.com/FrangSierra/firestore-cloud-functions-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

Let the app listen to some value in the firebase database and change it as the message you want.
I do this to my applications and its working like charm.

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered your application on FCM console? And added .json file in your application?

Comment: I made the Firebase project, added the .json, then connected my project from the Assistant Tool

Answer (score 1):

there are two types of notification data 
1)notification payload
2)data payload
if you send data from server in  notification payload mean. there is chance of not called onMessageRecieved() from FirbaseMessagingService have a look on [this link](http://developine.com/how-to-send-firebase-push-notifications-from-app-server-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a simple suggestion, but what caused a similar error to me a couple of weeks ago was that I sent the wrong form of notification.
I sent silent notifications, even though I should've send loud. Check how your server sends messages. I also messed up the order in which the FCM API expects the keys.

Here is my code for the working loud notifications, which are sent by a Django Python server:

```
def _build_loud_message(not_id, data):
    """Construct loud notifiation message.
    Loud means that this message will show up in the notifications hub
    of the app.
    """
    return {
        'message': {
            'notification': {
                'title': 'New activity',
                'body': 'Hey you have some new activity!'
            },
            'data': {"data": data},
            'apns': {
                'payload': {
                    "notId": not_id,  # notId HAS TO BE FIRST!!!
                    'aps': {
                        'badge': 1,
                        'sound': 'default',
                        'content-available': 1
                    }
                },
                'headers': {
                    'apns-priority': '10',
                    'apns-collapse-id': 'myid-1'
                }
            },
            'android': {
                'priority': "high",
                'data': {
                    "androidData": data
                },
                'notification': {
                    'sound': 'default',
                    'tag': 'mytag-1'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also pay close attention to the order in which the dic keys are mentioned. Changing them can cause the message not to be send successfully from FCM to the device, even though the FCM api says it did successfully sent.